# How does this happen? User with more rep gained than total rep

Tags: support, reputation

I just happened to look at the leaderboards today as I was bored, but I noticed this strange happening... How does a user have more rep gained for the timeframe than total rep? [image]

Comment: Bounties maybe?

Comment: ah that is possible.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I considered that, but I checked and that user hasn't offered any bounties.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141691/295232),

> - **Month reputation** is the amount by which your reputation changed that month, *excluding "private" reputation events.* Certain reputation events are excluded from your public user profile, such as deleted posts or downvotes,

This user seems to have (had) a high scoring answer, because they have a ["Good Answer" badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/good-answer?userid=41265) for an answer which has now been deleted. Those 250+ points are included in their monthly reputation but not in their total reputation.

Nice puzzle :)

Comment: Ah Thank you! that makes much more sense: